# SQLite запрос таблицы данных

Tags: sqlite, sql

Необходимо создать представление которое бы выбирало с таблицы данные таким образом.

```
Исходная таблица
Name Summ
Иван 1000
Пётр 2000
Павел 500
```

Полученное представление должно содержать список таким образом:

```
Name    Место по сумме(нужно именно так, а не отсортировывать)   Начисляемый бонус
Пётр        1                                                       100
Иван        2                                                       50
Павел       3                                                       40
...
...
```

Думаю сама идея понятна. Если кто то подскажет как это сделать буду очень благодарен. Сам не смог сделать потому что у SQLite нельзя объявлять и работать с переменными. А других идей как вставлять определённые значения(да даже циклически уменьшаемые) у меня нет.

Comment: Не обязательно давать мне готовый запрос. Просто подскажите, такое вообще возможно? И если возможно, то как примерно реализовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select Name , Summ, (select count(*) from таблица b  where a.Summ >= b.Summ) as cnt
from таблица a
```

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, поддерживает ли диалект sqlite функции ранжирования. Если нет, то [тут](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_numbering_rows_in_query.html) изложен подход, который будет работать точно.

Comment: К сожалению, это не подходит. Потому что  

    SELECT COUNT(*) no, P2.model 
    FROM Product P1 JOIN 
     Product P2 ON P1.model <= P2.model 
    GROUP BY P2.model

Подразумевает, что выборка идёт от начала таблицы. А мне нужна выборка с определённого места. И соединение будет не по числовому полю, а по текстовому.

Comment: Ладно, боюсь, что средсвами sqlite это сделать невозможно, либо настолько замудренно, что я сам не смогу. Спасибо за ссылку. Узнал много нового.

Comment: @istimbi, что же вас так смутило? Код, который вы привели, в вашем случае, будет не всей выборкой, а всего лишь одним доменом (столбцом). А далее соединяйте как хотите.

Comment: Подразумевает что выборка идёт от начала таблицы. А мне нужна выборка с определённого места - а что вы под этим имеете ввиду?